# Trouble using display: table and overflow: hidden in IE and Firefox (works in Webkit/blink)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**JSFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/h7xvr2t9/2/

---

I'm trying to implement a way to achieve a few effects:

- sliding a DIV into place that should be hidden below a visible container
- centering the text/image on a link to trigger the slide

### HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
            <a id="clickerthing" href="#" class="click">click</a>
            <div class="hidden">
                you can't see me until after the click... 
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    border: thin dashed black;
}

.outer {
    float: left;
    width: 235px;
    background-color: red;
}

.inner {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.click {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.clicked {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

The current code using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to position the contents properly for the link, and DIVs. The problem is that Firefox and IE handle this differently from Chrome/Safari. In the former browsers, the hidden DIV is always visible, while in the latter, it is hidden and respects the `overflow: hidden` CSS.

My main question is: **which browser is behaving correctly**? I couldn't find a clear answer on this, and most answers only suggested workarounds that were case-specific.

#### Bear in mind...

I noticed that adding a wrapping div around the container hides things as I want, but I'm still not sure why... : http://jsfiddle.net/h7xvr2t9/3/

Comment: OK, what is the status of the hidden div supposed to be, display-wise? Without a specific `display` property, it is a `block` directly in a `table`, which is an error according to the specs. (Same as writing `<table><div> ...`) So which browser is correct? Well, what is the correct way of displaying incorrect markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it without wrap div like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/h7xvr2t9/8/

```
div {
    border: thin dashed black;
}

.outer {
    float: left;
    width: 235px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow:hidden
}

.inner {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.click {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

.clicked {
    bottom: 0;
}
```